# Passing an array to an object as an argument

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and probably trying to do something stupid since an hour of googling didn't result in any examples.

I'm trying to learn objects so I made a constructor function like this:

```
//generic object
function clip(name, xposition, firstVisibleFrame, lastVisibleFrame, playStart, playEnd, defaultFrame, seqLoopStart, seqLoopEnd, backStateLevel){
this.name = name;
this.xposition = xposition;
this.outlinesArray =[];
this.firstVisibleFrame = firstVisibleFrame;
this.lastVisibleFrame = lastVisibleFrame;
this.outlinePath = ("outlines/" +this.name +"_");
this.playStart = playStart;
this.playEnd = playEnd;
this.defaultFrame = defaultFrame;
this.seqLoopStart = seqLoopStart;
this.seqLoopEnd = seqLoopEnd;
this.backStateLevel = backStateLevel;
};
```

Next I will create a new instance of that object with something like:

```
livingroomTable = new clip("livingroomTable");
```

...but now I'm really stuck because the next parameter I should pass to the function is actually a huge array with hundreds of values..

I tried to put the array inside the argument like this:

```
 livingroomTable = new clip("livingroomTable", [value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 and so on and so on]);
```

but this gives me a syntax error.

I don't want to make this array a global variable either. What is the correct syntax of passing an array of values as a part of the function call's arguments?

EDIT:

Here is the actual code:

```
//generic object
function clip(name, xposition, firstVisibleFrame, lastVisibleFrame, playStart, playEnd, defaultFrame, seqLoopStart, seqLoopEnd, backStateLevel){
this.name = name; //objektin nimi tulee funktion kutsusta
this.xposition = xposition;
this.outlinesArray =[];
this.firstVisibleFrame = firstVisibleFrame;
this.lastVisibleFrame = lastVisibleFrame;
this.outlinePath = ("outlines/" +this.name +"_");
this.playStart = playStart;
this.playEnd = playEnd;
this.defaultFrame = defaultFrame;
this.seqLoopStart = seqLoopStart;
this.seqLoopEnd = seqLoopEnd;
this.backStateLevel = backStateLevel;
};


livingroomTable = new clip(
"livingroomTable", //name

["1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1220.69","1216.69","1207.69","1194.69","1167.69","1157.01","1147.24","1137.62","1127.74","1118.55","1109.88","1100.17","1090.51","1080.69","1070.28","1059.5","1048.87","1038.21","1027.6","1017.31","1007.31","997.208","987.153","977.152","967.848","959.258","950.808","942.887","935.103","927.326","919.256","910.834","902.452","894.231","886.561","879.269","872.072","865.057","858.292","851.484","844.527","837.655","830.747","823.629","815.898","807.221","798.142","789.152","780.341","771.358","762.248","753.089","743.97","734.954","726.148","717.699","709.299","700.826","692.102","682.849","673.258","663.37","653.188","642.48","631.498","620.551","609.866","599.544","589.439","579.088","568.508","557.794","547.028","536.037","524.912","514.043","502.899","491.412","480.102","469.097","457.844","446.368","434.919","423.84","412.74","401.657","390.55","379.284","368.162","357.316","346.606","335.973","325.144","314.01","302.658","291.207","279.392","267.133","254.62","241.775","229.179","216.763","204.423","192.239","180.41","168.484","155.502","141.701","127.828","114.008","100.403","87.0368","73.5946","59.7342","45.3524","31.0484","16.8761","helmi.96","-11.522","-25.6947","-39.5332","-53.1723","-66.7146","-80.253","-93.1294","-106.086","-119.531","-133.534","-148.801","-165.444","-183.67","-202.813","-222.634","-242.769","-263.074","-283.495","-303.787","-322.998","-341.376","-359.338","-377.081","-395.064","-413.628","-432.233","-451.409","-472.675","-493.827","-515.078","-537.029","-558.747","-583.8","-610.595","-645.864","-695.789","-711.965","-737.979","-752.979","-836.048","-862.75","-864.75","-884.835","-911.473","-927.473","-969.103","-1030.36","-1002.83","-1036.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08"];, //xposition

352, //firstVisibleFrame

545, //lastVisibleFrame

2058, //playStart

2304, //playEnd

2175, //defaultFrame

-1000, //seqLoopStart

-1000, //seqLoopEnd

1 //backStateLevel

);
```

Hmmmm actually I think my problem is the semicolon at the end of array right? :D

Comment: If you're getting a *SyntaxError*, you'll need to show your actual code to get help.

Comment: okay but the array is going t be huge :D

Comment: http://www.jslint.com/ might help

Comment: You might want to consider passing JSON to the constructor, it's nicer.

Comment: @Sonypackman: That's alright.

Comment: If the array is huge, post a smaller example.  Learn to walk before running.

Comment: @Csongor Fagyal What does that mean? My current solution does not look very nice at all so I'm definitely interested if there is better ways!

Comment: @Sonypackman: Ignore that comment from Csongor Fagyal. It makes no sense. JSON is a UTF-8 text based, cross-language, data transfer format.

Comment: On "json-like" I mean instead of those ugly, hard to remember positional arguments you could use something like:

function clip(p) {
  // e.g. alert(p.name);
}

clip({ name: 'hello'});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a *SyntaxError* because you have a `;` semicolon at the end of the Array.

Remove that, and the error should go away.

```
["1220.69","1220.69", ..., "-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08"];, // <-- right here
```

---

It should look like this...

```
["1220.69","1220.69", ..., "-1048.08","-1048.08","-1048.08"], // <-- just a comma
```

---

You may want to consider using a code validator like [JSHint](http://jshint.com).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the principle that you are using.

You can put the array in a variable, and pass that to the function:

```
theArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
livingroomTable = new clip("livingroomTable", theArray);
```

Or you can use an array literal directly in the call:

```
livingroomTable = new clip("livingroomTable", [1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the assurance! I noticed my syntax error was caused by the semicolon (and earlier by and extra comma) :S Sorry for this!

Answer (score -1):

So, your constructor don't expect string and array parameters. You must call like that:

```
livingroomTable = new clip("livingroomTable", value1, value2, value3, value4, ...);
```